# How to set number into slider dot?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter. How can I set number on the slider dot?  [See expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXtYH.png)

Here is my slide code:

```
child: Slider(
  value: _value,
  min: 0,
  max: 10,
  divisions: 10,
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _value = newValue;
      //if (_value > 0) _picked = true;
    });
  },
),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SliderTheme widget as the parent of your Slider Widget to create a custom design for your Slider.

You can further follow this link:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html